# error while installing mod-wsgi 3.3 on mac os x

Tags: macos, apache, mod-wsgi

- apache 2.2
- mod_wsgi version is 3.3
- xcode 4 is intalled on my machine (is ther a issue with that?)

Steps:
1) ./configure
2)sudo make install

Step 2 gives following error

```
$sudo make install
/usr/sbin/apxs -c -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG  -Wc,'-arch x86_64' -Wc,'-arch i386' -Wc,'-arch ppc7400' mod_wsgi.c -Wl,-F/Library/Frameworks -framework Python -u _PyMac_Error   -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc7400 -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation  
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc7400 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework       
/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin     /ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
```

lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccuKotEU.out (No such file or directory)
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed the preview XCode from Lion on Snow Leopard and it doesn't have PPC, so doesn't match what Apache is compiled for.

Modify the Makefile manually and remove the -Wc,'-arch ppc7400' option.